# Problemas al trabajar con arraylist

Tags: java

Tengo una clase principal donde cargo los datos a un arrayList y una clase llamada material que llamo del arrayList para cargar datos .El problema que al cargar los datos desde la clase principal no tengo problemas pero si desde otra clase introduzco datos en esa arrayList me empieza desde cero. Me gustaria saber la forma de que esos datos se guardaran aunque yo este llamando desde varias clases a ese arrayList.Porque con una base de datos se podria hacer sin problema cargando los datos pero queria aprovechar este caso para manejar arrayList.

Un saludo y gracias por vuestro tiempo

Comment: Podrias agregar el codigo de las clases que mencionas

Comment: Por favor agrega un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Y si usas un arrayList estático?, este mantendrá los datos hasta el fin del ciclo de vida de la aplicación que estés construyendo.

ejemplo:

`public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 list.add("a");`

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que cuando llamas a tu arrayList desde la otra clase esta haciendo esto `miArray = new ArrayList();` lo que haces es crear una nueva instancia del mismo,
intenta declarandolo Static

Answer (score 0):

Obviamente la colección estará vacía si lo que haces es crear una instancia de la clase que contiene la colección. Esto sucede porque cuando una variable/campo/propiedad de una clase pertenece solo a la instancia que se cree de ella, mas no pertenece "a la clase".

Al pertenecer a la clase en lugar de a la instancia, lo que sucedería es que dicha colección sería estática y ya no dependería de la instancia.

```
public class Store {
    public static final List<Tipo> items = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Otra opción, a mi parecer mejor diseñada, es usar el **Anti**patrón [Singleton](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton), que consiste en compartir una única instancia a través de una aplicación entera.

```
public enum StorE {
  INSTANCE;
  private final List<Tipo> items = new ArrayList<>();

  public void addItem(Tipo item) {
      items.add(item);
  }

  public List<Tipo> getItems() {
      return items;
  }

  public Store getInstance() {
      return INSTANCE;
  }

}
```

Entonces, solo harías esto para obtener la instancia del Store:

```
Store store = Store.getInstance();
store.addItem(<<algo>>);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar el antipatrón singleton y para evitar definir la lista como `static final`, lo que puedes hacer es diseñar tu aplicación para que una clase, llamémosla `FuenteDatos`, contenga tu lista y todas las clases que necesiten acceder a esta lista deban recibir una instancia de `FuenteDatos` como argumento en el constructor para funcionar. Esto se llama relación de composición: la dependencia entre las clases y `FuenteDatos` es una dependencia fuerte, sin una instancia de esa clase las demás no pueden funcionar.

El diseño sería similar a esto:

```
public class FuenteDatos {
    private List<Dato> listaDatos = new ArrayList<>();

    public boolean agregar(Dato dato) {
        return listaDatos.add(dato);
    }

    //por poner un ejemplo
    public Dato buscar(int id) {
        Optional<Dato> dato = listaDatos.stream().filter(d -> d.id == id).findFirst();
        return dato.isPresent() ? dato.get() : null;
    }

    public void paraTodos(Consumer<Dato> funcionParaTodos) {
        listaDatos.forEach(funcionParaTodos);
    }
}
```

Y luego en las clases que lo necesitan:

```
//de acuerdo a tu descripción del problema
public class Almacen {
    private FuenteDatos fuenteDatos;
    public Almacen(FuenteDatos fuenteDatos) {
        this.fuenteDatos = fuenteDatos;
    }

    public void operacionX(Dato dato) {
        if (<reglas para validar dato) {
            fuenteDatos.agregar(dato);
        }
    }

    public void mostrarDatosEnConsola() {
        fuenteDatos.paraTodos(d -> System.out.println(
            String.format("Dato. Id: %d, Nombre: %s", d.getId(), d.getNombre())
            ));
    }
}
```

Y desde tu clase principal orquestas la integración de todos estos componentes:

```
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //aquí creamos la instancia de FuenteDatos
        FuenteDatos fuenteDatos = new FuenteDatos();
        //aquí creamos la instancia de Almacen
        //y la asociamos a FuenteDatos
        Almacen almacen = new Almacen(fuenteDatos);
        //puedes iniciar más clases necesarias para que funcione tu aplicación aquí
        //...
        //y que comience tu aplicación
        System.out.println("Bienvenido al Almacén.");
        //resto del código...
    }
}
```